# Get confused by the scope in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm learning angulaJS by the video [Introduction to Angular.js in 50 Examples](https://github.com/curran/screencasts/tree/gh-pages/introToAngular) , it's awesome but I'm confused since #46. We, say, want to get some nation's information from json file and display it, and we have a directive definition:

```
countryApp.directive('country', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            country: '=country'
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'country.html'
    };
});
```

and we invoke the directive country in some html:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="country in countries" country="country"></li>
</ul>
```

My question is: what the exact meaning of 4 different nouns "country" is?
the first two in directive scope(country: '=country' ), the last two in html(country="country"). I understand the first one is just a variable definition in directive,  so it should be change to another name such as dir_country, but it can't work !

Comment: I suspect the `li` element is wrapped in a controller?  The directive is receiving the country that would have been populated by the parent controller of the element

Comment: `_ - :` in attributes are converted to camelCase like dirCountry in angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example where they are all different:

```
<li ng-repeat="country in countries" country-dir="country">
```

```
.directive("countryDir", function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      countryObj: "=countryDir"
    },
    template: "<span>{{countryObj.name}}</span>",
    link: function(scope){
      console.log(scope.countryObj); // is the bound country object
    }
  };
});
```

Here:

- `country` is an inner scope variable of an item in array of `countries`
- `country-dir` is the directive (which has a normalized form of `countryDir`).
- `"=countryDir"` is a two-way binding to the `country-dir` attribute (which happens to be the directive itself, but doesn't have to be)
- `countryObj` is the internal isolate scope property that is bound to the `country` object, in case you want the internal name to be different than the attribute. Otherwise, it could have been shortened to `countryDir: "="`.

Comment: thanks  a lot . the key point is the third one . the scope variable countryObj can take any value passed from any attribute , but in this case happened to be the directive itself . and the directive also happened to be the same name as the scope variable in the original example. after I changed the name of the scope variable , I forget to  change the name in the html template named by templateUrl, so it doesn't work.

Comment: @eita, not sure I understand your question/issue